# How to transform GPS point from DECIMAL to DDD MM.MMM

Tags: gps

for example, i have this GPS Location: DECIMAL  39.48235 -0.38792

and i need to transform it to DDD MM.MMM    N 39° 28.941 W 000° 23.275

How to do it? I need to know necause i need to transform another GPS locations from DECIMAL to DDD MM.MMM

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty straight forward guide to it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_Decimal_Degree_to_DMS).

But the base of the calculation is like this:

Decimal input: 39.48235

Degress: 39 (whole number of the decimal)

Minutes: 28 = 28.941 = 0.48235 * 60  (fraction from the decimal multiplied by 60, and only accept the whole number)

Seconds: 56 = 56.46 = 0.941 * 60 (fraction from minutes multiplied by 60, and rounded)

Depending on the sign of the number and if it is lat or long will produce wheter it is's NSEW that should be pre/postfixed.

(Assuming you are using Java since your name is prefixed android you could have a look at the following [code](http://www.neptuneandco.com/~jtauxe/bits/LatLonConvert.java) if needed)

Answer (score 2):

The degrees value is just the integer component, e.g. 39 in 39.48235. To get the minutes value, take the fractional component of the decimal degrees value and multiply it by 60 (there are 60 minutes in a degree, and 60 seconds in a minute).

e.g. For latitude 39.48235, multiply 0.48235 by 60, which gives the minutes value of 28.941.

Do that for both the latitude and longitude, and then it's just a matter of formatting.